# Rails development.log not being written to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

In my rails app, when I first ran it, I got an error that said 'No such file or directory. log/development.log'
When I touched a development.log file, the app ran fine, but the file wasn't being written to by the logger. I tried changing the permissions on it to 666, but it still didn't work.

Comment: what's permissions on **log** dir?

Comment: permissions on the log dir are 777

Comment: Do you have **.gitkeep** file into the **log** directory? What is your **.gitignore** file?

Comment: i have no .gitkeep. My .gitignore is
.bundle
db/*.sqlite3
log/*.log
tmp/**/*

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the user that is running your app doesn't have write access to the log file.

Comment: I'm running the app locally and the permissions are set to 777.